# How do I drop values of a specific condition and replace those?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

| ID | first | second | fourth | fifth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one | one | Two | Three |
| 2 | one | Two | Two | Three |
| 3 | one | Three | Three | Three |
| 4 | one | one | one | one |
| 5 | one | one | two | one |

Code:

```
df = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'first': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'one', 'one']
'second': ['one', 'two', 'three','one','one']
'fourth': ['two', 'two', 'three','one','two']
'fifth': ['three','three','three','one', 'one']
        }
```

I want to drop/delete those values in one row that appear in the next column (right) as well.
So there are a lot of duplicates but if there is another value between one same value like in "ID" 5, then just the value of the second column should be deleted, so that the df looks like this in the end:

| ID | first | second | fourth | fifth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one | Two | Three | NaN |
| 2 | one | Two | Three | NaN |
| 3 | one | Three | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | one | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 5 | one | two | one | NaN |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do `shift` then use the NaN replace the same

```
out = df.where(lambda x : df.ne(df.shift(1,axis=1))).transform(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.isnull),1)
Out[73]: 
  ID first second fourth fifth
0  1   one    Two  Three   NaN
1  2   one    Two  Three   NaN
2  3   one  Three    NaN   NaN
3  4   one    NaN    NaN   NaN
4  5   one    two    one   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates` per row and reindex:

```
out = (df
 .set_index('ID')
 .apply(lambda s: (s2:=s.drop_duplicates())
                  .set_axis(s.index[:len(s2)]),
        axis=1)
 .reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
   ID first second fourth  fifth
0   1   one    Two  Three    NaN
1   2   one    Two  Three    NaN
2   3   one  Three    NaN    NaN
3   4   one    NaN    NaN    NaN
4   5   one    two    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: But it's not just duplicates. I need to delete those values which are the same as the one value to the right. In row 5 for example it should be: one, two, one, NaN.